# get client id of dynamically created dropdownlist for javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have made a page in aspx/c# , it takes input for generating dynamic dropdownlist on the next page.The dropdownlist is made multiple times through code behind depending upon the input in the previous page. Please suggest me how to get the clientID of the dropdownlist which will be generated on the next page.

//this is the functionality of the new page. How to get client Id of ddlTimeOfDeath dropdownlist

```
var tbl2 = new Table();
        tbl2.ID = "tbl2";
        tbl2.BorderWidth = 1;
        tbl2.Attributes.Add("Width", "100%");
        tbl2.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "tbl");
        tbl2.Attributes.Add("rules", "all");

        TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell00 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell11 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell22 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell33 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell44 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell55 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell66 = new TableCell();


        cell00.Text = "Sl No."; cell00.Attributes.Add("Width", "2%");
        cell00.Attributes.Add("class", "tblTDText"); cell00.Attributes.Add("align", "center"); row1.Cells.Add(cell00);

        cell11.Text = "Activity Name"; cell11.Attributes.Add("Width", "8%"); 
        cell11.Attributes.Add("Width", "20%"); cell11.Attributes.Add("class", "tblTDText"); row1.Cells.Add(cell11);

        cell22.Text = "Name of woman"; cell22.Attributes.Add("Width", "15%");
        cell22.Attributes.Add("class", "tblTDText"); cell22.Attributes.Add("align", "center"); row1.Cells.Add(cell22);

        cell33.Text = "Address of woman"; cell33.Attributes.Add("Width", "15%");
        cell33.Attributes.Add("class", "tblTDText"); cell33.Attributes.Add("align", "center"); row1.Cells.Add(cell33);

        cell44.Text = "Place of Death"; cell44.Attributes.Add("Width", "10%"); 
        cell44.Attributes.Add("class", "tblTDText"); cell44.Attributes.Add("align", "center"); row1.Cells.Add(cell44);

        cell55.Text = "Time of Death"; cell55.Attributes.Add("Width", "10%"); 
        cell55.Attributes.Add("class", "tblTDText"); cell55.Attributes.Add("align", "center"); row1.Cells.Add(cell55);

        cell66.Text = "Cause of Death"; cell66.Attributes.Add("Width", "5%"); 
        cell66.Attributes.Add("class", "tblTDText"); cell66.Attributes.Add("align", "center"); row1.Cells.Add(cell66);

        tbl2.Rows.Add(row1);
        for (int i = 0; i < actID.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            string actId = actID[i, 0];
            if (actId != null)
            {
                actId=actId.Trim();
                if (actId == "12" || actId == "39" )
                {
                    _objclstT389._i64T389001 = actId;
                    _objclstT389.fn_getRecordPr(_errMsg);
                    string actName = _objclstT389._strT389002;
                    int dcount = Convert.ToInt32(actID[i, 1]);

                    for (int j = 0; j < dcount; j++)
                    {
                        TableRow row = new TableRow();
                        TableCell cell0 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();


                        //cell1.Text = actID[i, 0] + "/" + actName;
                        if (j == 0)
                        {
                            cell0.Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
                            cell0.RowSpan = dcount;
                            cell0.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                            row.Cells.Add(cell0);

                            cell1.Text = actName;
                            cell1.Attributes.Add("valign", "top");
                            cell1.RowSpan = dcount;
                            row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                        }
                        cell2.Attributes.Add("valign", "top");
                        TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
                        tb1.ID="txtNameOFWman"+j;
                        tb1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        cell2.Controls.Add(tb1);
                        cell2.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                        row.Cells.Add(cell2); 

                        cell3.Attributes.Add("valign", "top");
                        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
                        tb2.ID="txtAddrsOfWman"+j;
                        tb2.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                        tb2.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        cell3.Controls.Add(tb2);
                        cell3.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                        row.Cells.Add(cell3);

                        cell4.Attributes.Add("valign", "top");
                        DropDownList ddl1 = new DropDownList();
                        ddl1.ID = "ddlPlaceOfDeath" + j;
                        ddl1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "-1"));
                        ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hospital","1"));
                        ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Home","2" ));
                        cell4.Controls.Add(ddl1);
                        cell4.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                        row.Cells.Add(cell4); 

                        cell5.Attributes.Add("valign", "top"); cell5.Attributes.Add("align", "middle"); 
                        DropDownList ddlTimeOfDeath = new DropDownList();
                        ddlTimeOfDeath.ID = "ddlTimeOfDeath" + j;
                        ddlTimeOfDeath.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        ddlTimeOfDeath.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:SelectedIndexChange('" + ddlTimeOfDeath.ClientID + "')");
                        ddlTimeOfDeath.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "-1"));
                        ddlTimeOfDeath.Items.Add(new ListItem("During Antenatal Period", "1"));
                        ddlTimeOfDeath.Items.Add(new ListItem("During delivery", "2"));
                        ddlTimeOfDeath.Items.Add(new ListItem("In postpartum report", "3"));
                        Literal ltlBrk1 = new Literal(); ltlBrk1.Text = "<br />";
                        TextBox txtDuration = new TextBox();
                        txtDuration.ID = "txtDuration" + j;
                        txtDuration.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        txtDuration.Width = 40;
                        Label lblDuration = new Label();
                        lblDuration.ID = "lblDays" + j;
                        lblDuration.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        lblDuration.Text = "Duration ";
                        TextBox txtNoOfDays = new TextBox();
                        txtNoOfDays.ID = "txtNoOfDays" + i;
                        txtNoOfDays.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        txtNoOfDays.Width = 40;
                        Label lblNoOfDays = new Label();
                        lblNoOfDays.ID = "lblDays" + j;
                        lblNoOfDays.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        lblNoOfDays.Text = "No. of days ";
                        cell5.Controls.Add(ddlTimeOfDeath);
                        cell5.Controls.Add(lblDuration);
                        cell5.Controls.Add(txtDuration); cell5.Controls.Add(ltlBrk1);
                        cell5.Controls.Add(lblNoOfDays);
                        cell5.Controls.Add(txtNoOfDays);
                        cell5.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                        row.Cells.Add(cell5);

                        cell6.Attributes.Add("valign", "middle");
                        TextBox tb3 = new TextBox();
                        tb3.ID = "txtCauseOfDeath" + j;
                        tb3.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        cell6.Controls.Add(tb3);
                        cell6.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                        row.Cells.Add(cell6);

                        tbl2.Rows.Add(row);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        phSecBActivity.Controls.Add(tbl2);
```

Comment: can you show some coding?

Comment: provide the functionality details

Comment: I have edited my question and have provided the coding, please reply